# Must the strong solutions of an SDE be unique? Can there be two different strong solutions?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

We know that the existence of solutions and pathwise uniqueness lead to the unique strong solution. And also that the strong solution is peculiar because of the fixed filtration.

I always see the discussion about "the unique strong solution". But I was wondering whether there could be strong solutions that are not unique? For example,can there be two strong solutions for an SDE given the same initial distribution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Example 1:** Note that stochastic differential equations (SDEs) are a generalization of ordinary differential equations (ODEs); in particular, any ODE which does not have a unique solution does not have a unique (strong) solution. Consider for instance the differential equation

$$dX_t =2 \text{sgn}(X_t) \,  \sqrt{|X_t|} \, dt, \qquad X_0 = 0;$$

it does not have a unique (strong) solution since both $X_t^{(1)} :=  t^2$ and $X_t^{(2)} := - t^2$ are a solution to the equation.

**Example 2:** The stochastic differential equation

$$dX_t = 1_{\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}}(X_t) \, dB_t, \qquad X_0 = 0$$

has more than one (strong) solution; just note that both $X_t^{(1)} := 0$ and $X_t^{(2)} := B_t$ solve the SDE.

Comment: Wow, these are such great examples! Thank you very much! @saz

Comment: @Pearl You are welcome. If you like the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: Ah, sorry I did not know that before. I have clicked it just now :) @saz

Comment: @Pearl Yeah, I thought so - that's why I told you about it. :)